# Spring Security get tokenValue from OAuth2AuthenticationToken

Tags: spring, security

I am currently using Spring Security to authenticate clients to Azure AD.
I would like to use the logged in users token to get access to another resource server on behalf of the user. To do so, I need the original token to use in the header.

When I debug my application, I am able to see the token under OAuth2AuthenticationToken.principal.idToken.tokenValue but I cannot use this in my code since principal is private (locked).

Is there another way to get the token value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find a solution.

public void getToken(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken, @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") OidcIdToken idToken) {

System.out.println(idToken);

}